# How can I save prevPath with context?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a small problem with **Go-back** buttons on my project. I want to share the problems with you.
Let's say, I have routes likes that;

`/products` ,
`/favorite-products`,
`/new-products`,

each of them contains products and when you click any of these products it will redirect you to `/products/:productId`.

In this single product page, I have `Go back` button when you click it will redirect to `/products`

But I want to redirect this user where it comes from. In this case if user comes from '`/favorite-products`' it redirected to `/products` but it should be `/favorite-products`

Note: I don't want to use `history.goBack()` because of the link sharing. And passing `states` with `react-router-dom` is not working also. Because in `products/:productId` page I have routed tabs (`products/:productId/comments`, `products/:productId/seller`) when user click one of them it's override the state so state will be `undefined`

I added Context like that,

```js
import { useState } from 'react'
import constate from 'constate'
import { Location } from 'history'

export const usePrevPath = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<string | undefined>()

  const setPrevPath = (location: Location) => {
    const { pathname, search } = location
    setState(() => `${pathname}${search}`)
  }

  return { prevPath: state, setPrevPath }
}

export const [PrevPathProvider, usePrevPathContext] = constate(usePrevPath)
```

```js
// on products list 
const location = useLocation()
const { setPrevPath } = usePrevPathContext()

return(
  <Link
  to='/products/:productId'
  onClick={() => setPrevPath(location)}>
  Product Name
<Link>
)
```

```js
// on Single Products 

const { prevPath } = usePrevPathContext()

// (?? '/products') for in case of user refresh the page
return (
  <Link to={prevPath ?? '/products'}>Go back<Link>
)
```

All good until here no problem,
But as I mentioned above I have a routed tabs here also like
Comments and Seller
Now, user go to `products/:productId/seller` and decided to click seller name it will redirected to '`/sellers/:sellerId`' page where there is GoBack button also which is work with same logic.
But now, I can not use my `prevPath` here because it's '`/products`' or '`/favorite-products`'.
But I have to use '`/seller`' here as a go back path.

You could say that, hard-code this `/sellers` inside `/sellers/:sellerId` as a go back button.

But it's not work also, because I need use go back here something like `/sellers?page=2`

Can anyone help me in this point ? Maybe I can pass another key to context along with location something like

```
onClick={() => setPrevPath(location, 'products')}>
```

where I can check on `/seller/:sellerId` page that is `prevPath.key === products` or `seller`

Comment: This smells a bit like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). A POP navigation action, e.g. `history.goBack()` is probably what you want. What I suspect is the issue or problem here is what you describe as the "tabs" part of the UI, which don't seem to maintain the history stack you desire so the UI ***can*** navigate back to the proper page. Can you [edit] to include a more complete and comprehensive [mcve] so we can see everything the relevant code is doing? You could also try creating a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that we could inspect live.

Comment: @DrewReese Hello Drew, 
If I will use the `history.goBack()` this time when I click the my Go back button on Single Product layout it will navigate between tabs also. And also one more problem with `history.goBack()` if user comes from shared link or google Go back button will not work correctly as well.

Comment: You shouldn't change the default "go back" navigation. It's reasonable users should go back one URL page entry when the click any "back" button. Like I said though, it seems your app is just pushing new entires into the history stack when navigating between tabs. You can manage the "forward" navigations so when the user does finally go "back" that they can get back to last "page" they were one prior to landing on the "tabs page".

Comment: See if my answer [here](/a/70251004/8690857) helps explain this a bit more clearly.